# How to get gatling simulations with changing random values in it

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

Gatling reads the scenario at the start of the simulation and then executes it several times with the same configuration/values.

How is it possible, for example, to execute each request with the following value "RANDOM-VALUE", always with a new random value?

```
val postRandomValue = scenario("Post Random Value")
    .exec(
      http("POST ShipmentList")
        .post("http://localhost:8080/endpoint") // Local
        .headers(Headers.header)
        .body(StringBody("myRandomValue: RANDOM-VALUE")))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Feeders](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder) will help here

```
val postRandomValue = scenario("Post Random Value")
.feed(Iterator.continually(Map(
  "RANDOM_VALUE" -> java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
)))
.exec(
  http("POST ShipmentList")
    .post("http://localhost:8080/endpoint") // Local
    .headers(Headers.header)
    .body(StringBody("myRandomValue: ${RANDOM_VALUE}")))
```