# Gatling session - get attribute as Long

Tags: scala, testing, gatling

I am a new in Scala and got some problems with casting from `String` to `Long`. I try to get Gatling session value as Long in request. Before in exec() part, I try to set the *userId* value

```
def setUserId(): ChainBuilder = {
    exec(session => session
      .set("userId", Random.nextLong())
    )
  }
```

Next, in request creator I want to use it like that because I need a new *userId* every call:

```
object UserRequestCreator {

  def sampleUserRequest(currency: String): Request = {

    Data data = new Data()

    data.setUserId("${userId}".toLong)
    data.setCurrency(currency)
  }
}
```

Test scenario:

```
exec(setUserId())
      .exec(http("postUser")
        .post(endpointUser).asXml
        .headers(headers)
        .body(StringBody(toXmlString(sampleUserRequest("EUR"), classOf[Request])))
        .check(status.is(200))
```

but receive error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${userId}"
```

How to fix that in Scala?
I also try Long.valueOf, JLong.parseLong("${userId"}, 16), Try(BigDecimal(...)) and more but nothing can help. I think the problem is with **$** symbol, but I don't see any different way to get this value from the session. Maybe it is possible to store Long in the Gating session?

Comment: It's not related to `.toLong` method (you'll get the same thing using Long.valueOf, etc,.). `"${userId}` is just literally the string itself, and has no numeric value actually.

Comment: so, how can I assure always newly generated numeric values in UserRequestCreator? Because when I put Random.nextLong to the UserRequestCreator I see the same generated value for all requests...

Comment: `"${var}"` syntax is interpreted by Gatling only in some places, not in regular Scala code. In your case I'd look at how to access the `session.get` from your method rather than using the string $ syntax.

Comment: Also, migt want to use a Feeder for providing random values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62811653/how-to-get-gatling-simulations-with-changing-random-values-in-it

Comment: @GaëlJ thanks for your help. One more question: why if I put the session into creator, I can't access stored session value like  `data.setMail("${user_mail}")`?

Comment: Because `${}` is only interpreted when the string is passed to a piece of code where Gatling expects the syntax. It's not interpolation like in plain Scala. It's more some kind of templating. Btw it's now `#{}` since Gatling 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#stringbody) and based on your current code, one way to do it is like that:

```scala
// with a function payload
http("name").post("/")
  .body(StringBody(session => s"""{ "foo": "${session("dynamicValueKey").as[String]}" }"""))
```

Thus, in your case:

```scala
StringBody(session => toXmlString(sampleUserRequest(session)("EUR"), classOf[Request])

def sampleUserRequest(session: Session)(currency: String): Request = {
  //...
  data.setUserId(session("userId").as[Long])
}
```